# ElasticSearch: Finding results where the content only consists of allowed characters, with optional x wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking to filter results by a set of allowed characters so that the remaining rows only consist of the allowed characters. But it should also allow for a x number of wildcards.

Any character in the allowed list is allowed to be used unlimited times so **a** matches **aaaaaa**. The wildcards could be either 1 use per wildcard or unlimited per wildcard, preferably a solution for both situations.

So an example where the allowed characters are [a,b,c] with 0 to 2 wildcards:

|  | **DataSet** |  |  | **No Wildcards** |  |  | **1 Wildcard** |  |  | **2 Wildcards** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *id* | *value* |  | *id* | *value* |  | *id* | *value* |  | *id* | *value* |
| **1** | aabc |  | **1** | aabc |  | **1** | aabc |  | **1** | aabc |
| **2** | aabcd |  | **4** | cba |  | **2** | aabc**d** |  | **2** | aabc**d** |
| **3** | axbd |  |  |  |  | **4** | cba |  | **3** | a**x**b**d** |
| **4** | cba |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | **4** | cba |

Answer (score 0):

First, add this custom filter;

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["my_char_filter"]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "[^abc?]",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_field": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use a regular expression query to find documents where the content only consists of allowed characters and optional wildcards:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "my_field": "^[abc?]{1,6}$"
    }
  }
}
```

Too allow only one wildcard use per value, you can use the following regular expression also;

```
"my_field": "^[abc]?[abc]?[abc]?$"
```

Comment: This works only for the example, but you cant build a analyzer for every query string that comes from the user searching.